# Making a div clickable and follow child anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, stoppropagation

i am currently working on making a div clickable, and when clicked it has to follow a link. This is my HTML:

```html
<div class="product">
 <form method="post" action="/shop/basket.asp" name="myform260020" id="productlistBuyForm750" onsubmit="return BuyProduct(this,'1','0','False');">
  <div class="image">
   <a href="/shop/boa-elektrisk-luftpumpe-750p.html" title="Boa elektrisk luftpumpe"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="prodinfo">
   /* Lots of text here */
   <div class="listprodbuy">
    <input class="BuyButton_ProductList" style="border:solid 0px black" src="/images/skins/Nordic%20Spring/images/add_basket.png" type="IMAGE"><br>
    <input name="AMOUNT" size="3" maxlength="6" class="TextInputField_Productlist TextInputField_ProductList BuyButton_ProductList" value="1" type="TEXT">
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

The idea is that when i click the div element with the class "product", it will follow the link wrapped in the div with the class "image". But when clicking the div with the class "listprodbuy", it will not follow that link.
This is my Jquery so far:

```js
$(".product").click(function(){
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
$("div.listprodbuy").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

When the main div is clicked, absolutely nothing happens, i assume that it is because the Jquery does not accurately pinpoint the link, as it is not a direct child element of the div. How would i go about specifying exactly which element it should follow?

While i would love to just wrap the entire div in an anchor, it's not possible because my CMS (DanDomain) wont let me access and edit the above HTML.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaco5157/1s134ubc/)

Comment: Why is the <a> link tag within the div not around it, wouldn't that just be easier

Comment: I would do so if i was able to. The only problem is that my CMS (DanDomain) is a pretty closed system, in which there are certain standard templates which cannot be accessed, the above HTML is one of those templates. 
The only way for me to edit is through css and Jquery

Comment: remove .div and just leave $(".listprodbuy").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: @Jacob I guess you forgot to add jQuery in your HTML. Here is the same working demo https://s.codepen.io/madhurgarg71/debug/vJrWVM/mWkoNbwJvZwA

Comment: I would really appreciate that, thank you. Would this script work for several of these divs with different links to follow? They all have the same layout.

Comment: @Jacob Yes, it should work.

Comment: It seems there is some resistance created by the input with the class `BuyButton_ProductList`

Comment: Yes that's the cause, when you try to do `window.location` through the `$('.product').click` event it somehow conflicts with the form submit validation, somehow that input with the class `BuyButton_ProductList` stays invalid here in my snippet, when I remove that input, the `window.location` just works fine perhaps is because it has an invalid image or something?

Comment: That is odd, could it be like Abdush explained that i should remove the .div before .listprodbuy and just leave $(".listprodbuy").click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });?

Comment: Yes it's because it has an invalid image, I just tested it with an existing image and it works fine

Comment: You mean removing the `div .prodinfo`, that is wrapping `div .prodsbuy`? I don't think it makes much of a difference. I believe the answer stays on that `input .BuyButton_ProductList` or some other input you migh have that is preventing a possible form submition!

Comment: Btw are you validating the form somehow? Does the form needs to be validated? If not, you can use the attribute `novalidate` ìn the `form` element, and it should ignore validation of inputs and allow the `window.location` to work.

Comment: Man just one more question! The div with the `a` element, can you put it outside the `form` element? If you can then there is no need for a `novalidate` attribute in the `form`, since your `a` or `click` _(I'm not sure which one is)_ is outside of it, It should be the `click`

Comment: Unfortunately i cant move any of the elements as this is a standard layout from my CMS that i do not have access to edit :(
I'm pretty sure that the form has to be validated, as it has something to do with Add to basket. I'll try to put a novalidate in the form and see what happens.

Comment: Ok I did some research, I we do `return false;` inside a form's jquery click listener, it should redirect, even if your form can't be submitted, you're already using that, here in my snippet its working just fine, I don't know exactly what I did.

Comment: So instead of directing the Jquery toward the .product div it should be directed towards the form?

Comment: I don't get it, in your jsFiddle itsn't it working just fine?, Wait, do you want to be able to click in the text _(without being exactly a click in the product image)_ and redirect? If it's that so then the problem is easy to solve!

Comment: Exactly, when you click anywhere within the border you should be redirected (to the same link that clicking on the image would redirect you to) Except when you click the green button, which is supposed to add the product directly to the cart.
I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` Should be set to absolute path instead of relative path. Since you are finding the href of anchor tag as `$(this).find("a").attr("href")`, It will give you the relative path. Just change html from `<a href="/shop/boa-elektrisk-luftpumpe-750p.html" title="Boa elektrisk luftpumpe"></a>` to `<a href="./shop/boa-elektrisk-luftpumpe-750p.html" title="Boa elektrisk luftpumpe"></a>` to get the absolute path.

Use `e.preventDefault();` along with `e.stopPropagation();` to avoid the postback.

*Complete Code:*

```js
$(".product").click(function(){
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
$("div.listprodbuy").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
   <form method="post" action="/shop/basket.asp" name="myform260020" id="productlistBuyForm750" onsubmit="return BuyProduct(this,'1','0','False');">
    <div class="image">
     <a href="./shop/boa-elektrisk-luftpumpe-750p.html" title="Boa elektrisk luftpumpe"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="prodinfo">
     /* Lots of text here */
     <div class="listprodbuy">
      <input class="BuyButton_ProductList" style="border:solid 0px black" src="/images/skins/Nordic%20Spring/images/add_basket.png" type="IMAGE"><br>
      <input name="AMOUNT" size="3" maxlength="6" class="TextInputField_Productlist TextInputField_ProductList BuyButton_ProductList" value="1" type="TEXT">
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked in my JSFiddle! There is one problem however, i cannot edit the href and add the dot as you suggest on my own site, because the HTML is part of a standard layout that i do not have access to edit (lousy CMS). 
Is it possible to convert from a relative link to an absolute one through Js as well? Something like .attr("(my website here)+href"); ?
Forgive me if that was way off, my knowledge on jquery is very limited

Comment: Yes you can form the absolute path using the current directory and concatenate with href.. to find the current directory, use  "window.location.pathname". It will give the path along with file. Use string's substring method to get the directory.

Comment: Use these line to get the absolute path.
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
var redirectTo = dir + $(this).find("a").attr("href");
alert(redirectTo);